# How windows phone app consume data from java webservice

Tags: windows-phone-7

i need to consume a java web service in my windows phone app but i don't know the exact procedure.but i tried the following code but its not working please tell me the exact procedure or a sample one.

```
ObservableCollection<Class1> p = new ObservableCollection<Class1>();

public Antocids()

{

    InitializeComponent();
    listBox1.DataContext=p; 

     ServiceReference3.ProductsClient client = new ServiceReference3.ProductsClient();
    client.getProdDetailsCompleted += new EventHandler<ServiceReference3.getProdDetailsCompletedEventArgs>(client_getProdDetailsCompleted);
    client.getProdDetailsAsync();
}

private void client_getProdDetailsCompleted(object sender, ServiceReference3.getProdDetailsCompletedEventArgs e)

{

    p.Clear(); // assuming you want to clear the data each time you get a new result 
    foreach(var result in e.Result)
      p.Add(result) 
}

//and this is my class

public class Class1

    {

        public string name { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: it is not working in what way? exceptions? hmmm?

Comment: yes error came at p.add(result);invalid parameters are passed

Answer (score 0):

e.Result is probably of type 'Object'.  Try casting it to the type you're expecting before doing the foreach loop.

I don't know what type you're expecting but if it were a string array then something like:

```
var myCollection = e.Result as string[];

foreach(var result in myCollection)
```